# No results in Highcharts with loading from JSON

Tags: php, jquery, json, highcharts

I am trying to display JSON DATA in a Highchart. Unfortunately without success. There are no JSON data transferred. No matter what I try. My question is how can I incorporate the following data in Highcharts? It should look like in the way in this [Tutorial](http://www.blueflame-software.com/blog/demo/using-highcharts-with-php-and-mysql/)

**highcharts.php**

```
$queryVLH = "SELECT
                CONCAT(Hour, ':00-', Hour+1, ':00') AS Hours,
                COUNT(visitor_date) AS `visitors`

            FROM
                (
                    SELECT  0 AS Hour
                    UNION ALL SELECT  1
                    UNION ALL SELECT  2
                    UNION ALL SELECT  3
                    UNION ALL SELECT  4
                    UNION ALL SELECT  5
                    UNION ALL SELECT  6
                    UNION ALL SELECT  7
                    UNION ALL SELECT  8
                    UNION ALL SELECT  9
                    UNION ALL SELECT 10
                    UNION ALL SELECT 11
                    UNION ALL SELECT 12
                    UNION ALL SELECT 13
                    UNION ALL SELECT 14
                    UNION ALL SELECT 15
                    UNION ALL SELECT 16
                    UNION ALL SELECT 17
                    UNION ALL SELECT 18
                    UNION ALL SELECT 19
                    UNION ALL SELECT 20
                    UNION ALL SELECT 21
                    UNION ALL SELECT 22
                    UNION ALL SELECT 23
                )   AS AllHours

            LEFT JOIN `visitors_table` 
                ON HOUR(`visitor_date`) = Hour AND DATE(`visitor_date`) = DATE(CURDATE())

            GROUP BY
                Hour

            ORDER BY
                Hour";

if(!$result = $mysqli->query($queryVLH)) {
    die($mysqli->error);
}

    // Output
    $rows = array();
    while ($r = $result->fetch_array()) {
        $row[0] = $r[0];
        $row[1] = $r[1];
        array_push($rows,$row);
    }

    echo json_encode($rows, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK); 

$result->free();
$mysqli->close();
```

My JSON data looks like this:

```
[["0:00-1:00",0],["1:00-2:00",0],["2:00-3:00",0],["3:00-4:00",0],["4:00-5:00",0],["5:00-6:00",0],["6:00-7:00",0],["7:00-8:00",0],["8:00-9:00",0],["9:00-10:00",0],["10:00-11:00",4],["11:00-12:00",0],["12:00-13:00",0],["13:00-14:00",0],["14:00-15:00",0],["15:00-16:00",3],["16:00-17:00",0],["17:00-18:00",0],["18:00-19:00",0],["19:00-20:00",0],["20:00-21:00",5],["21:00-22:00",0],["22:00-23:00",6],["23:00-24:00",0]]
```

I load the highcharts of many different ways. I currently have the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var chart;
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var options = {
                chart: {
                    renderTo: 'container',
                    defaultSeriesType: 'column',
                    marginRight: 130,
                    marginBottom: 25
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Hourly Visits',
                    x: -20 //center
                },
                subtitle: {
                    text: 'last 24 hours',
                    x: -20
                },
                xAxis: {
                    type: 'datetime',
                    tickInterval: 3600 * 1000, // one hour
                    tickWidth: 0,
                    gridLineWidth: 1,
                    labels: {
                        align: 'center',
                        x: -3,
                        y: 20,
                        formatter: function() {
                            return Highcharts.dateFormat('%l%p', this.value);
                        }
                    }
                },
                yAxis: {
                    title: {
                    text: 'Visits'
                },
                plotLines: [{
                    value: 0,
                    width: 1,
                    color: '#808080'
                }]
                },
                tooltip: {
                    formatter: function() {
                        return Highcharts.dateFormat('%l%p', this.x-(1000*3600)) +'-'+ Highcharts.dateFormat('%l%p', this.x) +': <b>'+ this.y + '</b>';
                    }
                },
                legend: {
                    layout: 'vertical',
                    align: 'right',
                    verticalAlign: 'top',
                    x: -10,
                    y: 100,
                    borderWidth: 0
                },
                series: []
            }
            $.getJSON("highcharts.php", function(json) {
                options.xAxis.categories = json[0]['data'];
                options.series[0] = json[1];
                options.series[1] = json[0];
                chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
            });
        });
</script>
```

Comment: what does your json look like before it goes to the chart series, i.e. what is the value of json inside of $.getJSON

Comment: The output of JSON data is available below the code of the highcharts.php if you mean!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format for highcharts needs to look like this, using UTC time format:

```
series: [{
    name: 'your name',
    data: [
        [Date.UTC(1970,  9, 27), 0   ],
        [25920000000, 2]
    ] 
}, {
    name: 'your name',
    data: [
        [Date.UTC(1970,  9, 27), 0   ],
        [25920000000, 2]
    ]
}];
```

So your function should look something like this:

```
$.getJSON("highcharts.php", function(json) {
    options.series[0].data = json[1];
    options.series[1].data = json[0];
    chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
});
```

Comment: It will not show any results. When I use the strtotime function for the $row[0] it will show a result only for 11 - 12 AM but nothing else

Comment: Care to make a jsFiddle with your data already hard coded... It is difficult to know what your issue is if I cant see all the pieces.

Comment: My code works now after some changes. But I dont know how to display the time correctly. Also it shows always January 1 as Date!

Comment: The problem is that first value for point should be number like `25920000000`, not `"2:00-3:00"`. IF you want to use your format, use categories for xAxis. Otherwise you need to change that values to timestamps in milliseconds.

Comment: Can I get an example for my complete code? Because I wanted to use already categories for the xAxis but it didn't work.

Comment: I don't have example code for you, sorry. Here is what you need to do:  1) remove axis type 2) remove labels formatter 3) use `xAxis: { categories: ['2:00 - 3:00', '4:00 - 5:00' ... ]`.